# Converter that converts EML files to plain text

Tags: gratis, email, document-converter, plain-text

I archived emails to a bunch of EML files, but the content isn't readable when such files are opened as plain text files.

I wonder if there is a converter (must be free) that can bulk convert EML files to plain text files containing subjects, content etc. (attachments could be ignored).

Comment: What OS? Must it have a GUI, or is command-line preferred?

Answer (score 4):

I took a kinda-working script [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392361/how-to-read-eml-file-in-python) and modified it to fit your needs.

You have to install [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/) for the script to run. When installing Python make sure to select `Add python.exe to Path`.

Anyways you save the script as `[whatever name you want].py` and put in the same folder as all your `.eml` files. Now just open the script. That's it.

It will create a folder `Email`. That folder has subfolders named the same as your `.eml` files. In THAT folders you can find all attachments and a .txt file with all email info:

- From
- To
- Subject
- Date
- Number of attachments
- Number of parts
- The message itself (duh.)

Note that some emails may contain HTML. This script does catch HTML but it saves it as plain text so you have to copy-paste the HTML part of the `.txt` file, save it as `.htm` and open it with any web browser.

Requirements:

- Free ✓

The script is below:

```
from email import message_from_file
import os

def file_exists (f):
    return os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, f).replace("\\","/"))

def save_file (fn, cont):
    file = open(os.path.join(path, fn).replace("\\","/"), "wb")
    file.write(cont)
    file.close()

def construct_name (id, fn):
    id = id.split(".")
    id = id[0]+id[1]
    return id+"."+fn

def disqo (s):
    s = s.strip()
    if s.startswith("'") and s.endswith("'"): return s[1:-1]
    if s.startswith('"') and s.endswith('"'): return s[1:-1]
    return s

def disgra (s):
    s = s.strip()
    if s.startswith("<") and s.endswith(">"): return s[1:-1]
    return s

def pullout (m, key):
    Html = ""
    Text = ""
    Files = {}
    Parts = 0
    if not m.is_multipart():
        if m.get_filename():
            fn = m.get_filename()
            cfn = construct_name(key, fn)
            Files[fn] = (cfn, None)
            if file_exists(cfn): return Text, Html, Files, 1
            save_file(cfn, m.get_payload(decode=True))
            return Text, Html, Files, 1
        cp = m.get_content_type()
        if cp=="text/plain": Text += m.get_payload(decode=True)
        elif cp=="text/html": Html += m.get_payload(decode=True)
        else:
            cp = m.get("content-type")
            try: id = disgra(m.get("content-id"))
            except: id = None
            o = cp.find("name=")
            if o==-1: return Text, Html, Files, 1
            ox = cp.find(";", o)
            if ox==-1: ox = None
            o += 5; fn = cp[o:ox]
            fn = disqo(fn)
            cfn = construct_name(key, fn)
            Files[fn] = (cfn, id)
            if file_exists(cfn): return Text, Html, Files, 1
            save_file(cfn, m.get_payload(decode=True))
        return Text, Html, Files, 1
    y = 0
    while 1:
        try:
            pl = m.get_payload(y)
        except: break
        t, h, f, p = pullout(pl, key)
        Text += t; Html += h; Files.update(f); Parts += p
        y += 1
    return Text, Html, Files, Parts

def extract (msgfile, key): 
    m = message_from_file(msgfile)
    From, To, Subject, Date = caption(m)
    Text, Html, Files, Parts = pullout(m, key)
    Text = Text.strip(); Html = Html.strip()
    msg = {"subject": Subject, "from": From, "to": To, "date": Date,
        "text": Text, "html": Html, "parts": Parts}
    if Files: msg["files"] = Files
    return msg

def caption (origin):
    Date = ""
    if origin.has_key("date"): Date = origin["date"].strip()
    From = ""
    if origin.has_key("from"): From = origin["from"].strip()
    To = ""
    if origin.has_key("to"): To = origin["to"].strip()
    Subject = ""
    if origin.has_key("subject"): Subject = origin["subject"].strip()
    return From, To, Subject, Date

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global path

    startdirname = "Email"
    num = 1
    for i in range(10000000):
        if os.path.exists(startdirname + str(num)) == False:
            os.makedirs("Email" + str(num))
            break
        else:
            num += 1


    for i in os.listdir("."):
        if i.endswith(".eml") == True:
            nam = i[:-4]
            path = "./" + startdirname + str(num) + "/" + nam

            os.makedirs("./" + startdirname + str(num) + "/" + nam)

            f = open(i, "rb")
            emailDict = extract(f, f.name)
            f.close()

            textFile = ""

            froms = emailDict["from"]
            tos = emailDict["to"]
            subject = emailDict["subject"]
            parts = emailDict["parts"]
            date = emailDict["date"]
            txt = emailDict["text"]
            html = emailDict["html"]

            files = []
            for i in emailDict["files"]:
                files.append(i)

            textFile += "From: " + froms + "\n"
            textFile += "To: " + tos + "\n"
            textFile += "Subject: " + subject + "\n"
            textFile += "Date: " + date + "\n\n"
            textFile += "Files: " + ", ".join(files) + "\n"
            textFile += "Parts: " + str(parts) + "\n\n"
            textFile += "Text:\n\n" + txt + "\n\n" 
            textFile += "HTML:\n\n" + html


            wf = open("./" + startdirname + str(num) + "/" + nam + "/" + "txt_" + nam + ".txt", "w")
            wf.write(textFile)
            wf.close()
```

Just realised how old this is. Hope you still need it! :P

Comment: I get:
```
python2.7 eml2txt.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eml2txt.py", line 125, in <module>
    for i in emailDict["files"]:
KeyError: 'files'
```
I wonder if it should be `msg["files"]` instead...

Comment: nope... don't really have the time to learn python now xD

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a little coding then you can do this in [python](http://www.python.org) as explained, with sample code, in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392361/how-to-read-eml-file-in-python) stack overflow question.

Python itself is:

- Free, gratis & open source
- Available for just about any platform
- The referenced example includes information about extracting attachments as well as the content.